# How to fix "vector subscript out of range" using mpi scatter?

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, boost-mpi

Problem is in my misunderstanding on how boost MPI wrappers work.
I am using Microsoft MPI implementation.
In this code I am trying to scatter `std::vector` to processes but get a debug assertion `vector subscript out of range` error.

This code is my bootstrap to implement hypersort algorithm using boost wrappers and Microsoft MPI.

I tried examples from boost libraries but got the same assertion.
Also I tried to include both `<vector>` and `<boost/serialization/vector>` but it didn't help.
I run my program on Windows 10 using boost 1.70 and latest version of Microsoft MPI.

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/collectives.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

#include "qsort.hpp"
#include "utils.hpp"

namespace algo {
namespace mpi_extension {

namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

void hyperqsort_v1(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    mpi::environment env(argc, argv);
    mpi::communicator world;
    int value = 0;
    int recv_value = 0;

    std::vector<int> unsorted_list{5, 3, 6, 2, 9, 1, 10, 7};
    auto distribuion_number = unsorted_list.size() / world.size();
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> unsorted_dist_list;
    if(0 == world.rank()) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < world.size(); ++j) {
            for(size_t k = 0 + j; k < distribuion_number + j; ++k) {
                unsorted_dist_list[j].push_back(unsorted_list[j + k]);
            }
        }

    }
    std::vector<int> recv_vector;
    recv_vector.resize(distribuion_number);
    mpi::scatter(
        world, unsorted_dist_list, recv_vector, 0);
}

} // namespace mpi_extension
} // namespace algo
```

qsort.hpp - sequential implementation of qsort algorithm

I expect all processes in communicator have their piece of unsorted list.

I can produce this error only in Debug build

Comment: ***I can produce this error only in Debug build*** I think that is because in release mode the check for out of bounds is not present. You still have some bug.

Comment: The first step is to have your debugger tell you what line contains the out of bounds access.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Correct way is to use std::vector::data() to get the address of first element.
May be it is specific only for Microsoft MPI implementation.

Example without rising debug assertion:
**mpiexec -n 4**

```
mpi::environment env;
mpi::communicator world;

std::vector<int> unsorted_list{11, 36, 44, 50, 53, 67, 86, 95};
std::vector<int> list;
list.resize(2);

mpi::scatter(world, unsorted_list.data(), list.data(), 2, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You only get that error in debug builds because the Microsoft compiler only includes that check in debug builds.  The problem still exists in a Release build.

If `world.rank()` is zero, `unsorted_dist_list` will be an empty vector when you use it in `unsorted_dist_list[j]`.  At a minimum, you should add

```
unsorted_dist_list.resize(world.size());
```

before the `for (size_t j = 0;` loop.

If `world.rank()` is not zero, `unsorted_dist_list` will be empty when passed to `mpi::scatter`.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I made my own solution.